# Wedge sum of simply connected spaces is simply connected?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Suppose X and Y are simply-connected. Then their wedge sum is simply connected?

My guess is yes, Their wedge sum,  $X \vee Y$ is simply connected.  But i couldn't get it rigorously.

Can you give me some hint or detail procedure for this statement?

Comment: The image of a loop will only cross the wedge point finitely many times (by compactness).  You can thus consider this image as the wedge of loops in finitely many components of the wedge.  Can you take it from there?

Comment: @SteveD: that's false! See the example in my answer where there are loops that cross infinitely many time.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip: Yes, OK, assuming path-connected and semilocally simply connected should be enough for it to be true, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your spaces are nice, then yes, Seifert-Van Kampen will show the wedge is simply connected. However, it's not true in general. Here's a counterexample due to Cannon and Conner ("On the fundamental groups of one dimensional spaces"). Take the Hawaiian earring space, $H$ and let $X=Y=C(H)$ be the cone on $H$. Now form a wedge sum $X\vee Y$ by identifying the two copies of the point where all the circles attach in $X$ and $Y$. $X$ and $Y$ are both contractible, but their wedge is not simply connected. See Example 2.0.2 of Cannon and Conner's paper.

Their paper is behind a paywall, so here is a screen shot of the relevant example 2.0.2.
[image]

Comment: I delete my answer since you are right.

Comment: What do you mean a nice space? At first glance i think simply connected space is enough..Actually i came up with this question from van-kampen theorem. (from the requirement of van-kampen, does open is enough for the nice space?)

Comment: Ah i got it, the other requirements of van kampen theorem is path-connected. I got it. Thanks

Comment: You need that at least one of the two spaces is well-pointed, i.e. the inclusion of the base point is a cofibration, @phy_math.

Comment: @phy_math: to apply Van-Kampen, you need a cover of your space by two open, path connected sets $U,V$ such that $U\cap V$ is path connected. For a wedge $X\vee Y$, you would take $U$ to be a small neighborhood of $X$ and $V$ a small neighborhood of $Y$. (So $U$ will contain a small neighborhood of the wedge point in $Y$.) In most cases (like CW complexes), $U$ actually deformation retracts to $X$, $V$ deformation retracts to $Y$ and $U\cap V$ deformation retracts to $X\cap Y$, so you can apply Van Kampen directly to $X$ and $Y$, rather than using the neighborhoods $U$ and $V$.