# Wedge of aspherical spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I‘d need a reference for the following fact: the one-point union of (nice) aspherical spaces is aspherical. I.e., from $\pi_kX=0$ and $\pi_kY=0$ follows $\pi_k(X\vee Y)=0$.
EDIT: Let‘s assume that the spaces are nice, e.g. manifolds.

[image: wedge of circles]

For the wedge of circles this is true because the universal covering space is contractible.

Comment: Is this not a counterexample? https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1790520/542740

Comment: What if both spaces are manifolds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer my own question (in the setting of CW-complexes and thus also for smooth manifolds):

According to Ganea [Link to Ganea‘s paper](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/ganea3.pdf) the homotopy fiber of $X\vee Y\to X\times Y$ is homotopy-equivalent to $\Omega X*\Omega Y$ if $X,Y$ are CW-complexes.

If $X,Y$ are aspherical, then their loop spaces are homotopy-equivalent to discrete spaces, hence the join of the loop spaces is homotopy-equivalent to a wedge of circles. In particular, $\Omega X*\Omega Y$ is aspherical. Since $X\times Y$ is aspherical, also $X\vee Y$ must be aspherical.