# Errors in my calculation of Euler characteristics of $\#\Bbb{T}^{2n}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebraic-topology, solution-verification, alternative-proof, characteristic-classes

> I want to find out the euler characteristics of the connected sum of $2n$-dimensional tori. Since we know that the euler characteristic of any odd-dimensional closed manifolds is $0$.

---

**My Attempt:**

The rank of $D_p(\mathbb{T}^{2n})$ is $\binom{n}{p}$, 
so we get the following chain complex with respect to $X=\mathbb{T}^{2n}$:
$$0\to D_{2n}(X)\to D_{2n-1}(X)\to...\to D_1(X)\to D_0(X)\to 0$$
Then, consider the boundary operator $\partial_{p+1}:D_{p+1}(X)\to D_p(X)$ which sends every $p+1$-cell to $0$ 
because $\partial_{p+1}(p+1\text{-cell})=a_1+a_2+...+a_m-a_1-a_2-...-a_m=0$.
which implies that $B_p(X)=\text{im}(\partial_p)=0$ and thus $Z_{p-1}(X)=D_{p-1}(X)$.

So, we conclude that $H_p(X)=D_p(X) \cong \bigoplus_{i=1}^{\binom{2n}{p}}\mathbb{Z}$.

Consider the space $\#_{j=1}^k\mathbb{T}^{2n}$ obtained by connecting finitely many $2n$-tori together. Then, we proceed by induction:

Consider the reduced homology exact sequence of a pair $(\mathbb{T}^{2n}\#\mathbb{T}^{2n},\mathbb{S}^{2n-1})$:
$$...\to \tilde{H}_p(\mathbb{S}^{2n-1})\to\tilde{H}_p(\mathbb{T}^{2n}\#\mathbb{T}^{2n})\to\tilde{H}_p(\mathbb{T}^{2n}\vee\mathbb{T}^{2n})\to\tilde{H}_{p-1}(\mathbb{S}^{2n-1})\to...$$
Then, by direct computation on the reduced version of Mayer-Vietoris Sequence with respect to $\mathbb{T}^{2n}\vee\mathbb{T}^{2n}$,
we can rewrite the reduced homology exact sequence as
$$...\to \tilde{H}_p(\mathbb{S}^{2n-1})\to\tilde{H}_p(\mathbb{T}^{2n}\#\mathbb{T}^{2n})\to\tilde{H}_p(\mathbb{T}^{2n})\oplus\tilde{H}_p(\mathbb{T}^{2n})\to\tilde{H}_{p-1}(\mathbb{S}^{2n-1})\to...$$

If $0<p<2n-1$, then $\tilde{H}_p(\mathbb{T}^{2n}\#\mathbb{T}^{2n})\cong\tilde{H}_p(\mathbb{T}^{2n})\oplus\tilde{H}_p(\mathbb{T}^{2n})\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^{2\binom{2n}{p}}\mathbb{Z}$.

If $p=0$, then $H_0(\mathbb{T}^{2n}\#\mathbb{T}^{2n})=\tilde{H}_0(\mathbb{T}^{2n}\#\mathbb{T}^{2n})\oplus\mathbb{Z}$.

If $p=2n-1$, then $\tilde{H}_{2n-1}(\mathbb{T}^{2n}\#\mathbb{T}^{2n})\cong\tilde{H}_{2n-1}(\mathbb{T}^{2n})\oplus\tilde{H}_{2n-1}(\mathbb{T}^{2n})\cong\bigoplus_{i=1}^{2\binom{2n}{2n-1}}\mathbb{Z}$
because both of the connected summands are compact orientable.

If $p=2n$, then $\tilde{H}_{2n-1}(\mathbb{T}^{2n}\#\mathbb{T}^{2n})\cong\mathbb{Z}$ because both of the connected summands are compact orientable.

Inductively, the homology groups for the connected sum of finitely many summands are:
$$H_p(\#_j^k\mathbb{T}^{2n})=
\begin{cases}
\bigoplus_{i=1}^{k\binom{2n}{p}}\mathbb{Z} & 0<p\le2n-1\\
\mathbb{Z} & p=0\text{ or }p=2n\\
0 & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$
which implies that the Betti numbers are:
$$\beta_p(\#_j^k\mathbb{T}^{2n})=
\begin{cases}
k\binom{2n}{p} & 0<p\le2n-1\\
1 & p=0\text{ or }p=2n\\
0 & \text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}
$$

Let $Y=\#_{j=1}^k\Bbb{T}^{2n}$. From the book Elements of Algebraic Topology written by Munkres,
we know that $\chi(M^n)=\sum_{p=0}^n(-1)^p\beta_p$.

In our case, $\chi(Y)=\sum_{p=1}^{2n-1}(-1)^p\beta_p+2=k\sum_{p=1}^{2n-1}(-1)^p\binom{2n}{p}+2=-2k+2$.

> 1. The euler characteristic is independent to dimensions!? so there must be some errors in my calculation, could someone help me please? (already solved by @William)

---

**Edit:**

According to William's comment, my result makes sense when we generalize the case of $2n=2$.

But still, I would like to observe this question from the following perspective (Q2) which I have no idea of how to start.

---

> **2. The wikipedia of Euler characteristics states that the case for orientable closed manifolds is a corollary of Poincare Duality. So I wonder how to use Poincare duality which relates homology with cohomology to deduce the same result.** Any hint/suggestions? Thank you very much.

Comment: I think there is no contradiction and you arrived at the correct value. By multiplicativity of the Euler characteristic $\chi(T^{2n}) = \chi(S^1)^{2n} = 0$, and if $M$ and $N$ are closed $2n$-dimensional manifolds then $\chi(M\# N) = \chi(M) + \chi(N) - 2$. It follows from these two observations that $\chi(\#^k T^{2n}) = 2 - 2k$ regardless of $n$ (when $k=0$ we have $S^{2n}$ which has Euler characteristic $2$ and every time we connect-sum a copy of $T^{2n}$ we subtract $2$).

Comment: @William OK, thank you. then I think this disproved a claim which states that the euler characteristic of any closed aspherical $2n$-manifolds (when non-vanishing) has the same sign as $(-1)^n$. Because connected sum of tori are closed aspherical but it's euler characteristics need not to have the same sign as $(-1)^n$ in general.

Comment: How do you see that the connected sum of tori is aspherical? I know it's true in dimension $2$ but I don't know how it works in higher dimensions.

Comment: @William Oh! Good point! I guess I just assumed something unproved. $\# T^{n}$ has to cover the n-torus or simply admits $\Bbb{R}^n$ as a covering space to make this true, but it's not proved in my argument or even false in general. Let me think about that, thank you.

Comment: @William Oh! I figured it out! the connected sum of two $n$-torus where $n\ge3$, is not homotopy equivalent to an n-sphere and hence not aspherical!!!!!!

Comment: Because If we assume the connected sum is closed aspherical then we can deduce that $M^n\# N^3\simeq M^n\vee N^n,n\ge 3$, because these two **cell complexes** have isomorphic fundamental group which implies the homotopy equivalence by the assumption, but their euler characteristics don't agree since $\chi(M\# N)=\chi(M)+\chi(N)-\chi(S^n)$ whereas $\chi(M\vee N)=\chi(M)+\chi(N)-1$. So we disproved my previous claim by contradiction.

Comment: I think I still don't follow a couple of your statements. Saying something "is not homotopy equivalent to an $n$-sphere and hence not aspherical" is not correct, since $S^1$ is the only aspherical sphere (the definition I'm used to is that $X$ is aspherical iff it is a $K(\pi_1(X), 1)$). It also seems like, in order to apply Whitehead's theorem, you're implicitly claiming that if $M$ and $N$ are aspherical then $M\vee N$ is aspherical as well. Do you see this by showing the universal cover is contractible?

Comment: I'm also looking for some clarification on your second question. What specifically is the result that you want to see as a consequence of Poincare duality? The computation of the Euler characteristic of $\#^k T^{2n}$?

Comment: @William Actually, I'm expecting to see what the exact case (euler charac) is for orientable closed manifold by asking question 2. I hope that's clear.

Comment: Well, I have not  shown the universal cover of $M\vee N$ is contractible, since intuitively, it should be aspherical as well. And I think that I will need to consider the universal covering $p:E\to M\vee N$ and $p^{-1}(M),p^{-1}(N)$ to show it. Apply Mayer-Vietoris sequence, I get $H_n(p^{-1}(M))\oplus H_n(p^{-1}(N))\cong H_n(E)$, then i get stuck because i don't know if there is a induced map from the universal covering of $M\# N$ to $E$ that gives me isomorphism on homology group. @William

Comment: It seems your intuition about the wedge of aspherical spaces is correct, but you have to be careful because in homotopy theory many things that seem "intuitively clear" end up being rather difficult, or even false. I found a [slick argument using homotopy fibres and a result by Ganea](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2982742/wedge-of-aspherical-spaces) but I think it ought to be possible to explicitly construct the universal cover for $M\vee N$ in an analogous way to constructing the universal cover for $S^1\vee S^1$, which is certainly doable but complicated to write down correctly.

Comment: @William Thank you for your hint, I'll try to get deeper into it.

Comment: @William I've been thinking about how to prove that the connected sum of higher dimensional torus is not aspherical for almost two months, but I couldn't proceed my argument. Maybe it's because I still need some more advanced knowledge to link homology with homotopy groups, so I decided to keep that question till I go to a university. Thank you for your help, Dr. William!